# Why can XmlSerializer serialize abstract classes but not interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

**Edit** This code should illustrate the whole problem:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(AThing1))]
public abstract class AThing
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(IThing1))]
public interface IThing
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AThing1 : AThing
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}

public class IThing1 : IThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<AThing> aThings = new List<AThing>(new AThing[] { new AThing1() { Name = "Bob" } });
List<IThing> iThings = new List<IThing>(new IThing[] { new IThing1() { Name = "Bob" } });

public void Test()
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        XmlSerializer aSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<AThing>));
        aSerializer.Serialize(sw, aThings);
        string text = sw.ToString();
    }

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        // This line will throw "Cannot serialize interface IThing.":
        XmlSerializer iSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<IThing>));    
        iSerializer.Serialize(sw, iThings);
        string text = sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

The first `text` generated by `aSerializer` will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfAThing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AThing xsi:type="AThing1">
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </AThing>
</ArrayOfAThing>
```

I don't see why can't `iSerializer` do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfIThing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <IThing xsi:type="IThing1">
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </IThing>
</ArrayOfIThing>
```

instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code? I don't think the code above will compile. Also, please post the code you use to serialize. It will make it much easier to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: See my update I think it should be pretty clear now.

Comment: For the record, what's the complete exception you receive?

Comment: "Cannot serialize interface IThing." is the inner most exception. The one on top wasn't any more helpful. But if you'd put the `List<IThing>` as a member in a class, you'd get something like "Cannot serialize member ... _because it is an interface_".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can serialize interface, but not as simple as classes:

http://ventspace.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/how-to-serialize-interfaces-in-net/

but to answer your question I have 2 guesses on this:

The first reason is from the practical side; The semantics of serializing an
interface are a little bit blurry. What do you you think the serializer
should serialize when you pass in an interface reference ? If you only
serialize the interface properties your deserialize then could wind up with
a half-way uninitialized object. There's no telling what that would do to
your application.

If you serialize the full object together with the type information then
serializing the interface really did not buy you anything. You could type
the reference as a class type in the first place if your application really
cares what object is there.

The second one goes with the stated purpose of the XmlSerializer. Despite
the misleading name XML Serialization in the .NET Framework really is a data
binding technology with the primary intention to map MXL data types defined
in XSD schemas to .NET types. The XSD definition knows about abstract base
classes, but since it's data centric, does not know anything about
interfaces. With that in mind there is little motivation to support
interfaces in the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 2):

The XmlSerializer is not serializing abstract classes. It is serializing one of several *concrete* classes.

Comment: Well, why can't it do the same with interfaces then?

Comment: The concrete classes I refer to are those you reference in `XmlInclude`

Comment: I understand what you are saying but don't understand what your point is. Why can't `XmlSerializer` serialize concrete classes that implement an interface just like it can serialize concrete classes that implement an abstract class, where the object to be serialized are in a list declared like the examples I gave in my question?