# WebAPI - Serializing an interface on complex class but still allowing concrete class to be serialized normally

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, nsjsonserialization

I would like to be able to build a solution using Microsoft ASP.NET Web API.  I would like to be able able to have a complex object like 'Person' below which implements an interface 'IDisplayInfo'.  When the Person is serialized, I would like all properties to be serialized normally, but when another object that only specifies the interface like the WorkOrder object is serialized, I would like only the properties on the interface to be serialized.  I would like it to work with both XML and JSON.  I tried overriding the DefaultContractResolver, but I'm having trouble understanding how this works.

Thank you for your help!

```
public interface IDisplayInfo
{
    string Id { get; }
    string Display { get; }

}

public class Person : IDisplayInfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Display { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class WorkOrder
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IDisplayInfo CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Serialized WorkOrder should look like this:
{ Title: "test", CreatedBy: { Id: "1", Display: "Bob Fox" } }

Serialized Person should look like this:
{ Id: "1", Display: "Bob Fox", FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Fox" }

Comment: I've added a link at the top of my answer that might be interesting. See if you can get done what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an attribute you might want to use:

[NotSerialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

This tells the serializer to skip that property.

---

You cannot do that. Serialization is based on concrete data, not on abstractions as is an interface.

Look here: [Why can XmlSerializer serialize abstract classes but not interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845615/why-can-xmlserializer-serialize-abstract-classes-but-not-interfaces)

Or this: [XmlSerialization with Interfaces](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bac96f79-82cd-4fef-a748-2a85370a8510/xmlserialization-with-interfaces?forum=asmxandxml)

That said, your solution might be a special separate type (at this point it might as well be a *struct*) that has a constructor taking in your class and copying the values. You can then serialize that:

```
public struct WorkOrderConcretized
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public PersonConcretized CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public WorkOrderConcretized(WorkOrder w)
    {
        this.Title = w.Title;
        this.CreatedBy = new PersonConcretized(w.CreatedBy);
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `PersonConcretized` struct will have to act accordingly.

Deserialization will be another story...