# Serialize interface as JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to write a .NET Core API that returns a list of objects. The following class is being used for sending responses:

```
class AnimalResponse {
    public IAnimal Animal { get; set; }
}
```

There is an empty interface:

```
interface IAnimal {

}
```

There are also 2 classes that implement this interface:

```
class Cat : IAnimal {
    public string CatProperty { get; set; }
}

class Dog : IAnimal { 
    public string DogProperty { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the `Animal` property of `AnimalResponse` class can contain either a `Cat` or a `Dog` class object. This is how I send response:

```
var response = new AnimalResponse() {
    Animal = new Cat() { 
         CatProperty = "Cat Property Value"
    }
};
return JsonResult(response);
```

For some reason `CatProperty` gets missing from an API response after serialization. API returns the following json: `{Animal:{}}`.

So, how do I make it include all the class-specific properties?

Note: I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult`, **not** `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Nope, it looks like it's impossible to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization of derived types works only if the variable type is `object`.

In other words, everything will work if you redefine your `AnimalResponse`:

```
class AnimalResponse {
    public object Animal { get; set; }
}
```

You lose a bit of type safety, but you can get around that like so:

```
class AnimalResponse {
    public AnimalResponse(IAnimal animal) { Animal = animal; }
    public object Animal { get; }
}
```

This works because `System.Text.Json` has a special case for `object`.

(There are a few articles out there that explain why and how to work with this, but unfortunately, it was a while ago since I found the one that actually made it clear for me.)

Answer (score 2):

1 install NewtonsoftJson

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

2 Configure Services

services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

Answer (score 0):

If you read also here [Why are interfaces not [Serializable]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639362/why-are-interfaces-not-serializable) interfaces are not serializable because they define a contract and not a data.

They are a way to define a behaviour for the class.

By the way you should be able to make it serializable by implementing the ISerializable interface.

EDIT: Consider using a base Class instead of an Interface if you only need to serialize data. If you need  to have both maybe a better solution is to have a base Class and an Interface and implement both.

UPDATE: Base class must implement the ISerializable interface.

Comment: The issue is still there after changing an interface to a class.

Comment: Make the class implement the ISerializable interface too. Sorry for the misunderstanding, an object that should be serialized must implement ISerializable, then in my opinion it's better that it is a class to implement it and not an interface, it could work too but IMHO it's going against the objectives of interfaces.