# What does [System.SerializableAttribute()] do?

Tags: c#

I am looking at somebody elses C# code and before a public enum there are the following lines:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
```

Can somebody explain in plain english what the `SerializableAttribute` line are does?

I already came across [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) - it didn't make much sense to me - I'm new at C#.

Comment: This is not someone elses code, this is generated code, generated by the xsd.exe.

Comment: It might be, but it isn't my code that's for sure :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The System.SerializableAttribute specifies to the runtime that the instances of that class can be serialized

Eg. You return an object in a WCF service call. If that object has this attribute and all of the objects inside it are serializable, the runtime will transform that object to JSON or XML, depending on the type of resource the web service returns.

Comment: Cheers - so basically, I can ignore it as it doesn't affect how I am using it.

Comment: WCF typically uses `DataContractSerializer`; `DataContractSerializer` doesn't actually need `[Serializable]` - it prefers `[DataContract]`

Answer (score 75):

This is actually quite subtle...

*On the surface*, the answer is simply "it adds the `SerializableAttribute` to the metadata for the class", where the purpose of `SerializableAttribute` is to advertise (to things like `BinaryFormatter`) that a type can be serialized. `BinaryFormatter` will refuse to serialize things that aren't explicitly advertised for serialization. This may be a consequence of `BinaryFormatter` being used to implement *remoting*, and to prevent data accidentally leaking across a remoting boundary.

Note that most serializers don't *care* about `SerializableAttribute`, so this *only* impacts things like `BinaryFormatter`. For example, none of `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer`, JSON.NET or protobuf-net really care about `SerializableAttribute`.

However, *actually*, it is ***not*** a standard attribute, but has special handling by the compiler:

- most attributes are technically `.custom instance` values (in IL terms)
- however, `SerializableAttribute` actually maps to a CLI `.class` flag, `serializable`

This doesn't change the *meaning*, but : as a novelty fact, `SerializableAttribute` is not actually implemented as an *attribute*.

Comment: Marc can you please elaborate on the IL part? What exactly does the change mean, and why does this attribute is handled differently? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is just long-hand for `[Serializable]`. It tags the class as one that can be 'converted' to and from other formats.

Common examples include 'Serialization' of a class 'to' a JSON or XML data structure, and also the equivalent conversion 'from' such structures.

Consider a class

```
[Serializable]
class MyClass
{
    public string Mem1 {get; set;}
    public string Mem2 {get; set;}
}

...
MyClass mc = new MyClass;
mc.Mem1 = "Hello";
mc.Mem2 = "World";
```

When serialised to a JSON structure, we get:

```
"{'Mem1':'Hello','Mem2':'World'}"
```

And given the two-way nature of the process, if we recieved information of this format (e.g. back from some web service), then we could happily Serialize it back into an instance of this class.

Building on the JSON example, we find a series of classes in the namespace `System.Web.Script.Serialization` that can help us with this. In particular, the `JavaScriptSerializer` class helps us with the provision of `Serialize()` and `Deserialize` methods.

Comment: Your examples of JSON or XML would typically use JavaScriptSerializer, DataContractSerializer, XmlSerializer or JSON.NET; not one of which cares about `[Serializable]`.

Comment: True, if indeed we could guarantee that it would only ever be serialized in this way.

Answer (score -1):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx):

> Indicates that a class can be serialized

See the documentation for an example.