# What's the sense of a [Serialize] keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, tags, language-lawyer

Yesterday and the day before, I've lost quite some time on a message, which was not received.
After quite some time, I realised that this was due to a missing `[serialize]` tag at the beginning of one of the classes, present in that message: as that tag was not present, the class could not be serialised, hence the message was not created and obviously not sent.

Now that I think about it: what's the sense of such a tag? Why doesn't the C# language (or the .NET technology in general) simply declare all classes as serialisable? What possible drawback would that cause?

Some people want to close this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461321/what-does-system-serializableattribute-do), but that question explains what the mentioned tag does, but not **why** it's not a standard configuration setting for all classes (hence the "language-lawyer" tag of this question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \[System.SerializableAttribute()\] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461321/what-does-system-serializableattribute-do)

Comment: @pfx: thanks for the quick reply, but as mentioned in the edit of my post, that post does not explain my question.

Comment: It's not default because most classes are _not_ intended for serialization and therefore do not need to obey the restrictions that being serializable comes with. Being serializable is the exception from the norm, not the other way round.

Comment: Neither mine, but do you happen to use BinaryFormatter?

Comment: As mentioned in the link by pfx, most serializers do not care about the `[Serialize]` attribute, and binaryformatter that *does* care is considered obsolete. So I do not think the attribute is needed for most modern code. If you are using BinaryFormatter/.net remoting I would recommend to migrate away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question that I think is answerable in a StackOverflow sense (though perhaps better at SoftwareEngineering.Stackexchange.com) is "What possible drawback would automatically declaring all classes as serializable cause?"

There are a few:

1. Not all classes have public member properties, which means the serializer implementations would have to decide what the default serialization behavior should be. Should it be "pretend this class doesn't exist?" Return null? String.Empty? Suddenly I also need an attribute for opting out of serialization.
2. It would require the serializers to always apply a default strategy for decisions about how to handle less trivial scenarios like circular references, and nested references in general, which can otherwise be ignored in trivial cases when serializability is opt-in. See [How to preserve references and handle or ignore circular references in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
3. Although there is already a security issue with the BinarySerializer even when opt-in, it would likely increase the attack surface area for other serializers if everything is serializable by default. See [Deserialization risks in use of BinaryFormatter and related types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)
4. Adding any default behavior like this has a potentially large implementation cost with a lot of hard-to-predict unwanted side effects, so "what is the cost of doing nothing?" ends up being a useful question instead.

Comment: It is worth noting that many modern serializers, like system.text.json *does* treat all classes as potentially serializable, and throw runtime errors if there are any problems with the type model. Attributes are only required if you want to deviate from the default behavior.