# Process similar to filesystem journaling or fault-tolerant logging to manage tasks?

Tags: c#, error-handling, journaling

Developing a c# application that will be running a series of tasks based on files the user uploads; this can take from a few seconds to a few days. I plan to implement some kind of logging system to resume work if the process gets interrupted. What is this log-for-interrupt/resume called and where can I learn more about existing implementations?

edit:

Useful things I've found so far:

> A journalled file system would use the same basic procedure, with a
>   few additional steps. Something like:
>
> - Journal entry: Moving file from A to B
>
>   - Physically copy old file to new location
>   - Update directory entry on new drive
>   - Remove directory entry from old drive
>   - Free space on old drive
> - Journal entry: Done moving file from A to B

from https://serverfault.com/questions/173176/what-is-a-journaling-file-system

---

> **Checkpointing**: The process of writing journaled metadata and data to their fixed-locations is known as *checkpointing.* Checkpointing is triggered when various thresholds
>   are crossed, *e.g.*, when file system buffer space is low, when there is little free space left in the journal, or when a timer expires.
>
> **Crash Recovery**: Crash recovery is straightforward in ext3 (as it is in many journaling file systems); a basic form of *redo logging* is used. Because new updates (whether to
>   data or just metadata) are written to the log, the process of restoring in-place file system structures is easy. During recovery, the file system scans the log for committed complete transactions; incomplete transactions are discarded. Each update in a completed transaction is simply replayed into the fixed-place ext2 structures.

from http://research.cs.wisc.edu/adsl/Publications/sba-usenix05.pdf (page 5)

---

edit 2:

I don't feel like I know much more about fault tolerance than when I first posted this question, but here's an outline of what I implemented.

Main first attempts for the job manager to load any existing saved state from a file, or creates a new empty manager.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
            _jxman = JobManager<Job>.Load(Properties.Settings.Default.JobJournalFilename);
    }
    catch
    {
            _jxman = new JobManager<Job>(Properties.Settings.Default.JobJournalFilename);
    }
    ...
    _jxman.Start();
    ...
}
```

And the JobManager class looks like this

```
public sealed class JobManager<T> : WorkGroupBase<JobBase>, IWorkSerializable where T : IJob
{
        #region Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// Hash goes here in file
        /// </summary>
        private const string _hashHeading = "SHA-256";

        /// <summary>
        /// Flag to know whether to update the journal
        /// </summary>
        private bool _isDirty = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Last time the journal was written to disk
        /// </summary>
        private DateTime _lastSaveTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Minimum time to wait before writing journal to disk again
        /// </summary>
        private TimeSpan _minTimeToSave = new TimeSpan(0,0,60);

        /// <summary>
        /// Threading object for lock
        /// </summary>
        private object _lock = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Thread to monitor status
        /// </summary>
        private Thread _watchDirtyFlag;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// journal file to track changes
        /// </summary>
        public string Filename
        {
                get;
                private set;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// default constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">Path to filename to write journal file</param>
        public JobManager(string filename) : base()
        {
                ConstructorHelper();

                Filename = filename;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses XML element to recreate the item
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xe">XML element used to create object</param>
        public JobManager(XElement xe)
                : base(xe)
        {
                // Checksum validation before doing anything else.
                // Will throw exception on failure.
                ValidateChecksum(xe);

                ConstructorHelper();

                string myName = "JobManager";

                XElement myself;
                try
                {
                        myself = xe.DescendantsAndSelf(myName).First();
                }
                catch
                {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Attempting to instantiate object, but no relevant information was found in the XML element");
                }

                Filename = myself.FirstElementValue("Filename");

                // Load up all the jobs
                XElement[] wq = myself.Descendants("WorkQueue").Elements().ToArray();

                foreach (XElement x in wq)
                {
                        try
                        {
                                IJob blarg = (IJob)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), x);
                                if (blarg != null)
                                        WorkQueue.Enqueue((JobBase)blarg);
                        }
                        catch
                        { }
                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for common constructing 
        /// </summary>
        private void ConstructorHelper()
        {
                // need to wait for the base constructor to finish before attempting to
                // hook events there
                base.QueueChanged += new EventHandler(JobManager_QueueChanged);
                base.HookQueueChangedEvents();

                _watchDirtyFlag = new Thread(WatchDirtyFlag);
                _watchDirtyFlag.Start();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the state of the JobManager to Filename using XML
        /// </summary>
        public void Save()
        {
                TextWriter writer = null;
                try
                {
                        writer = new StreamWriter(Filename);
                        writer.Write(this.ToXElement());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                        throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                        writer.Close();
                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the filename and attempts to parse it as XML to 
        /// create a JobManager. Pass the type of job to manage.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">File storing the JobManager as XML</param>
        /// <returns>JobManager with values loaded from file</returns>
        public static JobManager<T> Load(string filename)
        {
                if (filename == "")
                        throw new ArgumentException("Can not load JobManager: Filename not set");

                TextReader reader = null;
                string text;
                try
                {
                        reader = new StreamReader(filename);
                        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                        throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                        reader.Close();
                }

                XElement loadFrom = null;
                try
                {
                        loadFrom = XElement.Parse(text);
                }
                catch //(Exception ex)
                {
                        //throw ex;
                        loadFrom = new XElement("empty");
                }

                JobManager<T> output = new JobManager<T>(loadFrom);
                output.Filename = filename;
                return output;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the item to an XML element
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        new public XElement ToXElement()
        {
                XElement bxe = base.ToXElement();

                //string myName = this.GetType().Name;
                string myName = "JobManager";

                XElement wq = new XElement("WorkQueue");
                foreach (IWorkSerializable t in WorkQueue.ToArray())
                {
                        XElement addee = t.ToXElement();

                        wq.Add(addee);
                }

                bxe.Add(wq);

                XElement xe = new XElement(myName,
                        bxe,
                        new XElement("Filename", Filename)
                        );

                xe.Add(
                        new XElement(_hashHeading, Generic.ComputeSha256Hash(xe.ToString()))
                        );

                return xe;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates the checksum for the current xelement. Throws exceptions on failure
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xe">XML tree of the itme to validate</param>
        private void ValidateChecksum(XElement xe)
        {
                XElement checksum;
                try
                {
                        checksum = xe.DescendantsAndSelf(_hashHeading).First();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                        throw new Exception("Unable to find checksum node", ex);
                }

                XElement withoutChecksum = new XElement(xe);
                withoutChecksum.Elements(_hashHeading).Remove();

                string computedChecksum = Generic.ComputeSha256Hash(withoutChecksum.ToString());

                if (computedChecksum != checksum.Value)
                        throw new Exception("Checksum from XML element and checksum from contents of XML element do not match: \n" + xe.Value);


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This thread will watch the dirty flag, which is set everytime the 
        /// queues are changed. Every _minTimeToSave the flag is checked, and
        /// if the flag is set, Save() is called.
        /// </summary>
        private void WatchDirtyFlag()
        {
                while (true)
                {
                        // sleep until there's something to update
                        while (_isDirty == false)
                        {
                                Thread.Sleep(_minTimeToSave);
                        }

                        // but don't update too frequently
                        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastSaveTime) > _minTimeToSave)
                        {
                                // save first ...
                                this.Save();
                                // then update items ...
                                _lastSaveTime = DateTime.Now;
                                lock (_lock)
                                {
                                        _isDirty = false;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers

        /// <summary>
        /// updates flag when any underlying queue changes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void JobManager_QueueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                        _isDirty = true;
                }
        }

        #endregion
}
```

Things to note:

- This is incomplete code, in case anyone attempts to copy this (missing base class and things)
- Regular (binary) and XML serialization never quite worked correctly, so I implemented custom serialization which saves the object as XML. This is the `ToXElement()` method, and the constructor which takes an `XElement` argument.
- There's a checksum (SHA-256) included at the top level (JobManager) of serialization. When a new object is instantiated from an `XElement`, the checksum for the saved serialization object is compared to the checksum in the file.
- There's a static method `.Load(file)` which returns a new JobManager object by reading a file and attempting to deserialize the contents.
- Not shown here is the custom ConcurrentQueue class. This is a wrapper for the MSDN [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) class, but with an added event to notify when the queue changes.
- This JobManager class implements a base class with the aforementioned ConcurrentQueue; those queue change events are hooked in the constructor helper
- When the event fires, the JobManager sets a flag `_isDirty`
- The JobManager starts a thread on instantiation, which monitors the `_isDirty` flag. Most of the time is spent sleeping, but if at least `_minTimeToSave` has elapsed, the contents of the JobManager are serialized to disk. This should keep the JobManager from writing to disk too frequently.

Noted concerns not addressed:

- Are threads really the correct solution to watch the `_isDirty` flag?
- The JobManager (a single thread) manages Jobs (one at a time, but a different thread) which contain Tasks; there is no class-to-base-class synchronization to lock states while serializing
- Old completed jobs are serialized to disk and then reloaded

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about any existing system for this purpose but [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) is the key with which you can achieve this sort implementation. You just need to design your objects to support Serialization.

- *In case of task interrupt*, you can save or serialize the state of the object in any format (*Binary* or *XML*) on the filesystem.
- *In order to resume the task*, you just need to deserialize the objects and you are back in business.

To understand more about Serialization use following references:

1. [What is [Serializable] and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877808/when-should-i-use-serializable-in-c)
2. [.NET Serialization (using BinaryFormater, SoapFormatter and XmlSerializer)](http://www.dotneat.net/2009/03/22/NETSerializationUsingBinaryFormaterSoapFormatterAndXmlSerializer.aspx)