# Caching on filesystem

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am using System.Runtime.Caching for memory cache, but I would like to have a filecache aswell. I am having some trouble, seeing how to do this.
Of course, I can create my own, simply method of doing this. Save to disc, get from disc if it exists. BUT, can I do something more clever, with System.Runtime.Caching? Get expiration on the items, as an example?
I don't really see how to implement expiration, on my simple save-to-disc cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) is the key with which you can achieve this sort Caching on the FileSystem. First of all you must be having some object to Cache on the FileSystem. Include the Expiration time factor in it to check for its expiry (can be implemented using Timer) then you just need to design those objects to support Serialization.

To understand more about Serialization use following references:

1. [What is [Serializable] and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877808/when-should-i-use-serializable-in-c)
2. [.NET Serialization (using BinaryFormater, SoapFormatter and XmlSerializer)](http://www.dotneat.net/2009/03/22/NETSerializationUsingBinaryFormaterSoapFormatterAndXmlSerializer.aspx)

Comment: I am unsure about what you mean with a timer? If I create an object that has a timer and an expiration, then serialize it to disc, close my program and reopen it later. How will I get that object to expire, from the disc?

Comment: You can have an expiry information in the object. After deserialization you can use it to compare it with the current date and time to check if is expired or not. Later you can start some timer to check for the same infomration after regular internals. Hope this helps!