# Serialization of a class then getting the state back

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I have a class and I make it Serializable because I want to save the state. How do I get that state back?

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject 
{
  public int a = 5;
}
```

Related post where I learned about Serialization [What is [Serializable] and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877808/when-should-i-use-serializable-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change and save the state at runtime, a class with the Serializable attribute is the wrong way to go.

My guess is that the [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) will be good enough for what you are looking for. You could do something like this:

```
public static string playerPrefKey_a = "a_value";
public static int a
{
    get { return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(playerPrefKey_a); }
    set { PlayerPrefs.SetInt(playerPrefKey_a, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// (extension method) Deserializes a byte array into an object.
    /// </summary>
    public static T DeserializeToObject<T>(this byte[] buffer) where T : class
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add reasons for down voting for learning purposes. Thank you