# How to Rename xml element attribute when serialize?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, xml-attribute

I want xml with custom name for element atrribute, I declared the name as shown below

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "country")]
public class CountryInRegion
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "iso_code")]
    public string IsoCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "region_id")]
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "countries")]
public class Countries
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "country")]
    public IList<CountryInRegion> countries { get; set; }

    public Countries()
    {
        countries = new List<CountryInRegion>();
    }
}
```

and I get the output like this

```
<Countries>
 <countries>
  <CountryInRegion>
   <IsoCode>AD</IsoCode>
   <Name>Andorra</Name>
   <RegionId>EUROPE</RegionId></CountryInRegion>
  </CountryInRegion>
 </countries>
</Countries>
```

i tried [XmlElement(“name")] as well. but no changes is obtained

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you are generating the xml from the obj, you might want to explicitly declare the class as [Serializable] see [What is [Serializable] and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877808/when-should-i-use-serializable-in-c). Your renames look fine above.