# How to create serializable classes in C# using XMLs?

Tags: c#

I think it is possible to create classes in visual studio using XMLs but i don't know how to do that/ Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Look into [Serializable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877808/what-is-serializable-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps.

1. Copy XML
2. Open Visual Studio
3. Create a new Class
4. Go to Edit Menu
5. Select 'Paste Special > paste XML as classes.

Comment: Thanks. It is working good and sorry can't up vote as i don't have required reputation.