# How to fix serialize for table in Viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, serialization

I've declared a viewstate in my page like this:

```
public class TMP_RequestCourse
{
    public int CourseCode;
    public string CourseTitle;
    public int PriorityID;
}
public TMP_RequestCourse T_RequestCourse
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"] == null)
            return new TMP_RequestCourse();
        return (TMP_RequestCourse)ViewState["insertMode"];
    }
    set { ViewState["TMP_RequestCourse"] = value; }
}
```

but when page loaded, I recieve following error:

> Type 'App.UI.Pages.EduRequestEdit+TMP_RequestCourse' in Assembly 'App.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add [SerializableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) to your class.

```
[Serializable]
public class TMP_RequestCourse
{
    public int CourseCode;
    public string CourseTitle;
    public int PriorityID;
}
```

> When you create an object in a .Net framework application, you don't
>   need to think about how the data is stored in memory. Because .Net
>   framework takes care of that for you. However, if you want to store
>   the contents of an object to a file, send an object to another process
>   or transmit it across the network, you do have to think about how the
>   object is represented because you will need to convert it to a
>   different format. This conversion is called SERIALIZATION.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877839/3970411)