# Store 100000 records in session using MVC

Tags: session, model-view-controller, infragistics, iggrid

I am using Infragistics IGGrid with remote type pagination, sorting and filtering to display the records in MVC. In the server, the session state mode is "SqlServer".

I wanted to fetch 100000 records from database and due to nature of the IGGrid remote type feature, it will always be hitting the database.

As per the client policy I cannot hit the db and cannot store fetched content in external file for pagination, sorting and filtering.

As of now I am using Session to store those records and its working fine in local environment but after deployment on the Dev server I am getting error like I have to use Serializable to handle session.

Is there any alternate way to handle those huge dataset smoothly.

Comment: does the model implements `ISerializable`?

Comment: No. but let me know how to do this. what would be my web config configuration for SqlServer Session mode

Comment: sorry, i should say to add [`[Serializable]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877839/4648586) annotation to the classes being stored into session. this will be much easier to allow the class serialized into something else and stored into session. we dont have to think about the serialization details much.

Comment: Thanks @BagusTesa that resolves my problem