# C#: What members will be serialized to XML element when making a class [Serializable]

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

Given a class marked as `[Serializable]`, how to we know whether the member of it will be serialized or not (**the member has no attribute**) by `XmlSerializer`?

For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class C2
{
    public int x1 = 1;
    private int x2 = 2;
    public static int x3 = 3;
    public readonly int x4 = 4;

    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public static int Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

We have a class `C2`, and after serialized a new object `C2 c = new C2()` into XML string, I found that only `x1` and `Y1` are serialized. So I **infer** that:

1. `public` field and property will be serialized.
2. `private` field and property will not be serialized.
3. `static` and `readonly` field and property will not be serialzed.
4. MethodInfo will not be serialized.
5. ...

My question is that is there any guidelines to know that: without marking any attribute to a member of class, how do we know that this member will be serialized or not?

Comment: used xmlserializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XML serialization does not use `SerializableAttribute` there is no difference in what properties will be serialized to XML with or without `[Serializable]` on the class (see [What is [Serializable] and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877808/what-is-serializable-and-when-should-i-use-it) for reasons to use it).

You seem to already correctly got list of what is serialized from [Introducing XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization):

> XML serialization serializes only the public fields and property values of an object into an XML stream. XML serialization does not include type information.