# << SerializationException : Type 'UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour' ... is not marked as serializable >>?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, save

I would like to save the data with a binary form but it doesn't work and says << SerializationException: Type 'UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour' in Assembly 'UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable. >>
Do you know what is the problem?

Here is some parts of my << DataManager >> Script :

```
public class DataManager : MonoBehaviour {
private string dataPath;

public void Initialize() {
    dataPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/gameData.dat";
}

public void Save(GameData gameData) {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(dataPath);

    GameData data = new GameData();
    data.level = gameData.level;
    data.hp = gameData.hp;
    data.mp = gameData.mp;
    data.damage = gameData.damage;
    data.exp = gameData.exp;
    data.maxExp = gameData.maxExp;
    data.equipItem = gameData.equipItem;

    bf.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();
}
```

And here are some parts of << GameManager >> script :

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
private static GameManager m_instance;
public static GameManager instance {
    get {
        if (m_instance == null) {
            m_instance = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
        }
        return m_instance;
    }
}

private DataManager dataManager;
public GameData gameData;

public event Action levelUp;
public bool isPlayerDead { get; private set; }


public void Awake() {
    if (instance != this) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    dataManager = GetComponent<DataManager>();
    dataManager.Initialize();

    LoadGameData();

    levelUp += UpdateMaxExp;
    levelUp += UpdateMaxHp;
    levelUp += UpdateMaxMp;
    levelUp += UpdateLevel;

    FindObjectOfType<PlayerHealth>().onDeath += PlayerDeath;
}

public void SaveGameData() {
    dataManager.Save(gameData);
}

public void OnApplicationQuit() {
    SaveGameData();
}
```

This is the GameData script :

```
namespace DataInfo {
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GameData {
        public int level = 1;
        public float hp = 100f;
        public float maxHp = 100f;
        public float mp = 100f;
        public float maxMp = 100f;
        public float damage = 25f;
        public float exp = 0f;
        public float maxExp = 100;
        public List<Item> equipItem = new List<Item>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the implementation of `GameData` ?

Comment: @derHugo yes I added it.

Answer (score 2):

In general **you should NOT use [`BinaryFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) anymore at all!**

Consider rather serializing via [`JSON`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) or [`XML`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer)

---

Also in general don't use `+"/..."` for system paths. As different platforms use different system path separators you should rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which always uses the correct separator depending on the platform (OS)

```
dataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "gameData.dat");
```

---

Finally **don't directly (de)serialize a `MonoBehaviour`!**

It makes no sense since a `MonoBehaviour` may not exist without being attached to a `GameObject` .. so you can't deserialize it (in a valid way) anyway and using `new` on it is forbidden .. which is what the `BinaryFormatter` internally does.

The only exception for this is stuff like [`JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html) since it doesn't create a new instance but rather overwrites the fields of an already existing one.

Rather use a "normal" [`[Serializable]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html) data contianer class. As soon as a script is

- not directly related to a specific GameObject
- doesn't need any `MonoBehaviour` messages like `Update`, `Awake` etc

It should not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` at all but rather simply store the data like e.g.

```
// not a MonoBehaviour since it has no own behavior anyway
// So this doesn't need to be attached to a specific GameObject but rather simply exists
// somewhere in a field or property
[Serializable]
public class GameData
{
    // Your fields here
}
```

and in the manager have

```
public GameData gameData = new GameData();
```

Comment: Oh lol I am studying with a book and there was a binary formatter part. Okay I won't use it. Thank you for the answer. But the GameData not inherit from MonoBehaviour and I serialized a GameData type data.. which part is the problem again ?

Comment: And what is `Item`? Is that a `MonoBehaviour` ?

Comment: No It's also a class serializable in the DataInfo

Answer (score -1):

Your `GameData` class needs to have a [`[Serializable]` attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html). Depending on what's in that class, you also might want to define how it is serialized.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877808/what-is-serializable-and-when-should-i-use-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) question might also help.