# What does the [Serializable] attribute do that ISerializable doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between using the Serializable attribute & implementing ISerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365152/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-serializable-attribute-implementing-is)

What does tagging a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) with [`Serializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) do? e.g.:

```
[Serializable]
public Hashtable 
{
}
```

How is it different from the [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) implementing [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)? e.g.:

```
public Hashtable : ISerializable
{
}
```

And how is *that* different from tagging the [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) as [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) and implementing [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)? e.g.:

```
[Serializable]
public Hashtable : ISerializable
{
}
```

What is the purpose of `[Serializable]` as opposed to `ISerializable`?

**tl;dr**: What is `[Serializable]`?

Comment: From your own links: "If a class needs to control its serialization process, it can implement the ISerializable interface"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365152/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-serializable-attribute-implementing-is

Comment: @BFree *"The above indicates that the serializing facility should serialize the entire class 'MyFoo' whereas..."*   ...Whereas....whereas...what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I thought you'd linked to [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx), but you didn't:

> All the public and private fields in a type that are marked by the `SerializableAttribute` are serialized by default, unless the type implements the `ISerializable` interface to override the serialization process.

and,

> Apply the `SerializableAttribute` attribute even if the class also implements the `ISerializable` interface [...]

That is, the `Serializable` attribute indicates that this type *can* be serialized. `ISerializable` indicates that this type wants to control *how* this type is serialized.

---

Or, to put it another way, your question is phrased the wrong way around. `SerializableAttribute` should *always* be applied (to serializable classes), and is the "basic" level of serialization. `ISerializable` adds more (by allowing you to write code to control the process).

Comment: What does it mean then if you tag some public or private field in a type as `[Serializable]` but not others? Isn't that nonsensical?

Comment: @IanBoyd - if you manage to tag a field with it, and it compiles, it means your compiler isn't following the attribute usage hints, sints it's declared to only apply to classes, structs, delegates and enums.

Comment: Ohhh...so a class can be serialized, and not even **need** to implement `ISerializable`. Tricky!

Answer (score 4):

`ISerializable` means you have to override/implement the method `void GetObjectData`

The `[Serializable]` directive lets the compiler know this class can be serialized. And the CLR will throw an exception if the class doesn't meet the requirements: ie Default Constructor, unknown types, etc